# How do I convert a LED PIR Light to a switched only light

Tags: electrical

I have a 10w LED PIR light with a faulty sensor. The light works fine on its own but only stays on for a few minutes when switched off and then back on again.
How do I convert this light to a switched on and off light only and do away with the faulty sensor?
There are 4 wires (2 brown and 2 black) coming from the PIR that are attached to the circuit board. Can send in a photo of the circuit board if that would help.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: A digram or picture would really help, but even then it might be tough to figure this out.

Comment: This is rather important in this case:  What's the make and model of the light?   Also what was your motivation in buying a PIR light in the first place?

Comment: Also, is it your intent to also use a light switch?  How do you want that to work?

Comment: In response to why I bought a PIR in the first place. This PIR light is a faulty unit that was replaced under warranty and they didn't want the faulty unit back. As I am keen on re-cycling or finding a use for things that otherwise might be discarded it seemed a pity to just bin it!!
I'll now put that up in another place as a switched light.

Comment: Please don't post answers replying to multiple people; use the "add a comment" link underneath their posts instead.

Answer (score 1):

I looked online for a schematic diagram (a picture might help but probably not) and I didn't find any with 2 brown and 2 black wires.

You should see if you could possibly replace the PIR with a direct replacement.

If you proceed to hack the light you risk making it unusable. Of course in its current condition that would be the case.

Without a schematic, my slightly educated guess would be, that if you cut the two brown wires and wire nut them together and then do the same with the black wires you will bypass the PIR. This is just a guess from the information you have posted. If it trips the breaker or the magical black smoke comes out of it, then you will know that was the wrong thing to do. Proceed at your own risk!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I did try joining each of the black and brown wires together thinking that they would close those two circuits and allow the light to switch on but not the two browns and blacks together. I have just joined the two brown wires and blacks together and now

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that worked!!!
I had tried joining the brown and blacks wires together thinking that would have completed those two circuits but wouldn't have thought that joining the two brown and two black together would make any sense as I would have thought they were on two separate circuits.
Thanks for all the replies and especially yours :)